# statsmodels ARIMA.fit: Hide output

Tags: python, statsmodels, scientific-computing

It seems whenever I run `ARIMA.fit()`, I always get a stdout from the kalman filter:

```
## -- End pasted text --
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

           * * *

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =            1     M =           12
 This problem is unconstrained.

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds

At iterate    0    f=  5.60459D-01    |proj g|=  2.22045D-08

           * * *

Tit   = total number of iterations
Tnf   = total number of function evaluations
Tnint = total number of segments explored during Cauchy searches
Skip  = number of BFGS updates skipped
Nact  = number of active bounds at final generalized Cauchy point
Projg = norm of the final projected gradient
F     = final function value

           * * *

   N    Tit     Tnf  Tnint  Skip  Nact     Projg        F
    1      1      3      1     0     0   0.000D+00   5.605D-01
  F =  0.560459405131994

CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL

 Cauchy                time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Subspace minimization time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Line search           time 0.000E+00 seconds.

 Total User time 0.000E+00 seconds.
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious parameter to pass into fit to hide this output. How do I hide this output?

Comment: try to add `disp=0` to the `fit` call. `iprint=0` will also suppress the lbfgsb log file, hopefully.

Comment: `arima.fit(disp=0)` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

From @user333700's comment, use:

```
arima.fit(disp=0)
```

The [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit.html) (for version 0.7.0.dev-c8e980d) says:

> disp : bool, optional
>
> > If True, convergence information is printed. For the default l_bfgs_b
> >     solver, disp controls the frequency of the output during the
> >     iterations. disp < 0 means no output in this case.